# subvectorsapce base for ${R_{sym}^{9\times9}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

what  is the  base of subvectorsapce   ${R_{sym}^{9\times9}}$=$\{A \in {R^{9\times9}}  \mid {A^{tr}}=A\}$ in ${R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subspace OP asks is the space of symmetric matrices.
It has dimension $\dfrac{9\times10}2=45$
One of its basis is given as: $\{A:a_{ij}=a_{ji}=1,\text{otherwise }0\}$ where $i,j$ runs from $1$ to $9$.
$9$ of them has only one $1$ on the main diagonal. $(i=j)$
$36$ of them has two $1$'s, symmetric about the main diagonal $(i\neq j)$.